# Uso e significato della locuzione "dal vero e dal vivo"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La chimera*, di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto:

> Visto **dal vero e dal vivo**, finché visse, fra’ Domenico Buelli da Arona, professore di teologia, inquisitore del Sant’Uffizio e padre priore dei Domenicani di Novara, era stato un bel fratacchione basso e grasso, calvo e rubizzo: dogmatico, come richiedeva il suo ufficio e anche di più; ambizioso, come si conveniva ad un uomo che aveva avuto per maestro ed amico uno dei padri della Controriforma cattolica, il cardinale Antonio Ghislieri; il quale cardinale, divenuto Papa con il nome di Pio V, aveva poi continuato a favorirlo assecondandone anche i difetti: primo fra tutti, la megalomania.

Ho cercato l'espressione "dal vero e dal vivo" nel dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli e in qualche altro dizionario, ma non l'ho trovata. Potreste spiegarmene il significato e farmene qualche esempio perché possa capire come usarla?

Comment: Se racconto di qualche evento dal vero e dal vivo, intendo che sono stato personalmente presente (dal vero) e proprio nel momento e/o posizione  più significativo (dal vivo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le locuzioni "dal vero" e "dal vivo" significano in pratica entrambe la stessa cosa; la prima si usa spesso
nelle arti figurative.

Prendo la definizione dal vocabolario Treccani

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vivo/

> la locuz. avv. o agg. dal vivo è com. anche in espressioni come una
>   vicenda, una scena, un’immagine ripresa dal v., dalla realtà, da
>   quanto realmente accade ed esiste o è accaduto ed esistito.

Inoltre: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vero/

> La realtà esistente e concreta, spec. in quanto soggetto di
>   rappresentazione artistica: tenersi, attenersi al v.; studiare,
>   copiare, rendere il v., e disegnare, dipingere, ritrarre dal v., dal
>   modello reale;

Nella frase utilizzata,  *"Visto dal vero e dal vivo"* significa appunto *"visto com'è nella realtà"*. L'uso di entrambe le locuzioni serve a rafforzare il concetto.

Mi pare di capire che l'autore con la conoscenza *"dal vero e dal vivo"*
del personaggio non si riferisca solo al suo aspetto "esteriore" ma indica anche la conoscenza della personalità o indole dello stesso.